# Passing arrays as input to user defined functions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

If you want to pass vectors (or arrays) as input to some user defined function to make some operations with them, you can pass the components:

```
def sample(X_0,Y_0)
    #here X_0 and Y_0 are some components of the arrays X and Y
    #do some operations with those components of X and Y like
    scalar= X_0+Y_0
    return scalar
number=sample(X[0,0],Y[0,0])
```

or pass the vectors and decompose then inside the function:

```
def sample(X,Y)
    #here X and Y are arrays
    #do some operations like
    scalar=X[0,0]+Y[0,0]
    return scalar
number=sample(X,Y)
```

which is the preferred method and why?

Comment: If you are not trying to modify the arrays in place, they are very equivalent.

Comment: Neither, because you throw away the result of both functions.

Comment: @Learningisamess thanks, any optimal solution?

Comment: @roganjosh Ok, let's say the result is used for something, I simply forgot to add number=sample(X,Y) or the like to use it later

Comment: Do whichever makes the most sense for the application. Pass the whole vector if the function needs to deal with it as a whole, pass individual elements if the arrays are not relevant to the function.

Comment: What's the important, or distinctive, part of this function?  Adding two variables, or indexing the variables as `[0,0]`?  Is there another function that does a subtraction?  or another that does `X[10,12]+Y[30,23]`?

Comment: @Barmar Ok, thanks!

Comment: @hpaulj The operations are not important in the context of my inquiry. I was rather curious if there are "best practices" when passing (vector or array) arguments to user defined functions. For the sake of the argument, let's say you use all components on the computations. Is it better to first decompose and then send? or to send first and then decompose?

Comment: numpy arrays often have thousands of elements and several dimensions.Passing components changes the array to scalars or a tuple (with the *args argument), loosing any benefits of starting with an array.

Comment: If the arrays are just a source of a couple of the numbers, pass those numbers, not whole arrays.  That way the user function doesn't need to know anything about the arrays  And it can be tested with just a couple of numbers, rather than whole arrays.  On the other hand it the function makes use of the whole arrays, then pass them whole.

Comment: If the purpose is to process arrays, pass the whole arrays. If the purpose is to process scalars, and it doesn't matter that they came from numpy arrays, just pass the elements. A function is supposed to be reusable, so think about all the uses of the function.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, there is absolutely no difference between the two outputs as you bind the results to `scalar`. In python, you tend to pass arrays and lists by reference and primitives by value. So when can you expect to see a difference?

Consider the function:

```
>>> def manipulateX(X):
...     X[len(X)-1] = -1
...     return X
...
```

When you call `manipulateX` with a list (as follows), you see that the list is also manipulated:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> manipulateX(x)
[1, 2, 3, -1]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, -1]
```

However, if you define a function which operates on a primitive

```
>>> def manipulateY(Y):
...     Y += 20
...     return Y
...
```

and call it with an item in a collection (list, array) etc:

```
>>> manipulateY(x[0])
21
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, -1]
>>>
```

You see that `x[0]` remains unchanged. In your case as you bind your results to `scalar` you don't see any difference. In both the cases, your memory usage is also the same. If you weren't binding the results to `scalar` then it depends on whether you want `x[0]` and `y[0]` to be muted.